# Swift command line tool for mouse clicks will not multi-click in Finder

Tags: swift, cocoa, click, mouse

I'm using the code below in a command line tool app to perform mouse clicks. I use a shell script to execute the code, and a dictation command to trigger it. This code will work in just about every program except Finder, and I don't know why. Single mouse clicks work fine, but not double or triple. I don't know what the problem could be.

```
// Get location
var ml = NSEvent.mouseLocation
ml.y = NSHeight(NSScreen.screens[0].frame) - ml.y
let location = CGPoint(x: ml.x, y: ml.y)


// Clicks
let e = CGEvent(mouseEventSource: nil, mouseType: .leftMouseDown, mouseCursorPosition: location, mouseButton: .left)!
e.setIntegerValueField(.mouseEventClickState, value: 2) // double click
e.post(tap: .cghidEventTap)

CGEvent(mouseEventSource: nil, mouseType: .leftMouseUp, mouseCursorPosition: location, mouseButton: .left)!.post(tap: .cghidEventTap)
```

Comment: A double click is mouseDown, mouseUp, mouseDown, mouseUp (a normal click followed by a click with `mouseEventClickState` 2). Did you try posting four events instead of one (like you did in your previous question)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go

```
/// Clicks left mouse button twice
static func doubleClick() {

    var e = CGEvent(mouseEventSource: nil, mouseType: .leftMouseDown, mouseCursorPosition: Mouse.location, mouseButton: .left)!
    e.post(tap: .cghidEventTap)
    e = CGEvent(mouseEventSource: nil, mouseType: .leftMouseUp, mouseCursorPosition: Mouse.location, mouseButton: .left)!
    e.post(tap: .cghidEventTap)

    e = CGEvent(mouseEventSource: nil, mouseType: .leftMouseDown, mouseCursorPosition: Mouse.location, mouseButton: .left)!
    e.setIntegerValueField(.mouseEventClickState, value: 2)
    e.post(tap: .cghidEventTap)

    e = CGEvent(mouseEventSource: nil, mouseType: .leftMouseUp, mouseCursorPosition: Mouse.location, mouseButton: .left)!
    e.setIntegerValueField(.mouseEventClickState, value: 2)
    e.post(tap: .cghidEventTap)
}
```